# Flutter Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform Error

Tags: java, flutter, ubuntu

I'm trying to make an http post request to save a user from a flutter app running on a real device. I'm running a Springboot RESTful API on an ubuntu server with nginx set up. A postman request is able to be sent. I have already tried adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to my application tag in my android manifest and I have tried adding a `network_security_config` and added that to my application tag along with the meta-data tag inside the application tag.

Here is my network_security_config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Here is my code for my flutter app calling the api:

[image: Here is my code for my flutter app calling the api:]

Here is my Springboot RESTful API code:

[image: Here is my Springboot RESTful API code]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Uri.https
```

and not

```
Uri.http
```

Comment: Well this throws a handshake error which I could solve by setting up SSL but this is just a test environment for learning flutter so http would be ideal.

Comment: Do you have this in your Manifest?

<application ...>
  ...
  <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
             android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
</application>

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my issue! The issue was that I was adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the wrong android manifest file. Previously I had it under android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml but the proper spot is under andoird/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml. As stated in https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android